# appendChild is not a function - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I know this is a very common error, but I just can't figure out why this isn't working.

I want to change the value of a span dynamically. Simple, right? I've tried $span.innerHTML = "text" and $span.innerText = "text", which do nothing, but don't throw any errors. My most recent attempt looks like this:

```
var $resourceSpan = $("#divname"+dynamic_variable);
var stringVar = functionThatReturnsString();
      while( $resourceSpan.firstChild ) {
        $resourceSpan.removeChild( $resourceSpan.firstChild );
      }
      var textNode = document.createTextNode(stringVar);
      $resourceSpan.appendChild( textNode );
```

Does anyone know why I'm throwing this error? Thanks

Comment: Isn't `$resourceSpan.firstChild` a function? You'd need () after it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dealing with jQuery object, methods like removeChild() and [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) belongs to dom element not to the jQuery object.

To remove all contents of an element you can use [.empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty) and to set the text content of an element you can use [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text), but using .text() will replace existing content so in your case you can just use

```js
var $resourceSpan = $("#divname" + dynamic_variable);
var stringVar = functionThatReturnsString();
$resourceSpan.text(stringVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you wanna do somethin like this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>STACK OVERFLOW TESTS</title>
    <style>

    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <span>HI, IM SOME TEXT</span>

    <input type = 'button' value = 'Click me!' onClick = 'changeText()'></input> <!-- Change the text with a button for example... -->

    <script>
        var text = 'I AM THE NEW TEXT'; // The text to go in the span element

        function changeText(){
            var span = document.querySelector('span');
            span.innerHTML = text;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```